# JQuery Ajax Post results in 500 Internal Server Error $.ajax (anonymous function) under Linux server

Tags: jquery, ajax, anonymous-function

I am getting an (anonymous function) in my chrome inspector console which says it is because of the line in my script: $.ajax({

Heres the code. Thanks for help.

```
$('#form-new_login').find('span i#ajax_loader').css("display","block");//Ok
$('#img_log').attr('src','images/onoffline.png');//Ok   
$('#form-new_login').find('input.ise_button.icon-paper-plane').val('En cours...');//Ok
var verif1=verif_ise_login($('input#ise-form-login'),6);//Ok
var verif2=verif_ise_password($('input#ise-form-pass'),6);//Ok
if (verif1 && verif2) {//Ok
    $.ajax({// *********** Pb. is here *******************
    //[cursor before char a of ajax({ Error : POST 500 (Internal Server Error), details : (anonymous function)]
    type: "POST",
    url: $('#form-new_login').attr('action'),//"modules/membres/profil/mon_profil.php",
    data: $('#form-new_login').serialize(),
    cache: false,
    success: function(data)
    {
    ...
    }
```

here the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmUnh.jpg)

Comment: Can you post the whole error you get in the Chrome console?

Comment: Maybe I’m not getting it right, but HTTP 500 is the response from the server: there is nothing wrong with the `$.ajax()` call itself. The problem is on the server side.

Comment: Thnks Davide for ur answer : i just added a picture. Refresh F5 Thanks a lot

Comment: Thnks Vlad for "The problem is on the server side" : i think too

Comment: Thnks to all. I have to contact the admin & sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

**Solved** for me. Advice for such error(Error 500 *Internal server error* ) : This error triggered because an instruction php is rejected by the server. Review the code of the called file line by line. Example for my Correction (I just changed $_POST to $_REQUEST)